# Windows Phone 8 In-App purchasing queries

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am just setting up in-app purchasing within my app .. it will be a single 'Durable' item that I am allowing the users to purchase.

I have got it going in testing with the MockIAP project, but it does raise some questions.

My Durable purchase will be an 'upgrade to pro' so I named the key as 'ProUpgrade' within the mock initial setup.

- when I go to purchase the product within  my app, the message  asks if I want to buy (ProUpgrade).  Is this  the only name/description that is visible to the user?  I thought  that there were more descriptive terms that could be entered as part of associating the product to the app?
- how will this work in a multi language app?  The Key I am checking for is my 'ProUpgrade' key and presumably that is the name across all languages.  It would be nice if a translatable name could be entered in the description (i.e. a different one for each language)  but then as per my first point - not sure if that will ever be displayed.  Perhaps this is clearer when the product is added to app as part of the submission, but I haven't got that far yet.
- because I have a single product, i was not retrieving the product list for the app and was going straight in to check if its been purchased

  if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["ProUpgrade"].IsActive)

But as I found out, this a bit dangerous if its not in available product licenses. (Got an exception)  Whilst I feel that I could rely upon my single product being there, presumably best to make the call to get all product licenses and check to see if its there?

Answer (score 2):

In DevCenter, when you define your product (IAP) - you have to enter product alias,id (key) display name and description and list of languages. In the later stages in the product definition, depending on the earlier language selection, it asks for respective translations of the product definition etc.

This is the only place, where you define the IAP product info for all languages(if you decided to translate them), otherwise default language content will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Is the In-App Purchase in windows phone 8 is same as Windows Store apps(Coding are all same)? and If its same means In Dashboard of Windows Store apps we provide feature name to identify the particular product for purchase. But in windows phone 8 Dashboard there is nothing to be like that(I didn't even find the Feature name to be asked in windows phone 8 Dashboard) Help to sort out

Comment: I am not much familiar with Windows Store apps, but for WP8 DevCenter - in order to add new "in app purchase" product - first click the app and then click "products" - this where you will manage the IAP's and can add new IAP there...hope it is clear?