# How to determine if a user purchased an App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I was wondering how can I determine though code, if a user did buy our App through the Windows Store.

Because we have a payed App, and I found it for download on eg. FileDir as an .xap file. Fully working.

We are not working with in-app purchases or trial version, you have to pay for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783302/windows-phone-8-in-app-purchasing-queries

Comment: I know but we are not using an in-app purchase key to upgrade to pro. I just want to know how I can determine if a user / person bought the App through the store.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not the original developer (logged in with the same account) XAP installation through SD Card or download will still require you buy the application. If you have already bought it in the past it will not ask again as it will verify that with the Windows Phone Store.

Is that your question?

If you are asking how to check from one app if another one has been bought the best option is to check the list of installed apps:
[InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

To check if license is still active you can check in the code:

```
bool hasBeenBought = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsActive;
```

Comment: We are the Original developers of the App. But we found .xap files of the App for download on different file sharing sites, and they were fully functional.

Comment: We just want to check when someone install .xap file manual on their Phone, if our App for this user / person has beens bought through the Store, otherwise navigate the user to the store for buying.

Comment: ah somebody changed your code so in general piracy: sorry to hear that! In such case I guess the best option is to check in the code if the license is active as in my example.

Comment: I guess the bool hasBeenBought just checks if the current microsoft account has bought the app and his license for the app is still valid

Comment: Is this not what you need? It check with the Store if user has license for the given app: if he/she downloaded the modified version it will return `false` as the user has not got the license in the store portfolio.

Comment: This works for Windows Phone 8 how to do this for Windows Phone 7

Comment: You are right: there is no `LicenseInformation` for WP7 and it seems there is is no straight forward way of verification, yet I have an idea how to do it: I will check if after hours (in the evening) and let you know.